# Attempt to de-reference a null object - error in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am trying to update business unit field in business_unit__c custom object. for this we have used custom settings in trigger and if manually any sales rep is creating based on their role we created a new process builder to update the field. Now, I am getting this error in test class if process builder is active.

Below is my test class:

```
@isTest
private class BusinessUnitTriggerHandlerTest 
{
    static testMethod void testCheckDuplicate() 
    {

        Profile profile = [Select Id from Profile where name = 'ORT Direct Sales User'];
        User nonAdminUser = new User( ProfileId = profile.Id, Username = System.now().millisecond() + 'test2@test.com.dev',UserRoleId = '00E1G000000IX0IUAW',
                                    Alias = 'batman', Email='bruce.wayne@wayneenterprises.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',Firstname='Bruce',
                                    Lastname='Wayne',LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',LocaleSidKey='en_US',TimeZoneSidKey='America/Chicago' );
        System.runAs(new User( Id = UserInfo.getUserId() ))
        {
            Database.insert(nonAdminUser);
        }

        Account acc = TestUtility.createAccount( TestUtility.default_account_rt, false );
        acc.Name = 'sfdcpoint';
        acc.Account_Status__c = 'Active';
        insert acc; 

        System.runAs(nonAdminUser)
        {
            Contact cont = TestUtility.createContact( TestUtility.default_contact_rt , acc, false ); 
            cont.MailingStreet = 'Test Street' ;
            cont.MailingCity = 'Minneapolis';
            cont.MailingState = 'MN';
            cont.MailingPostalCode = '55347';
            cont.MailingCountry = 'United States' ; 
            insert cont;

            BusinessUnits__c bu = new BusinessUnits__c( Contact__c = cont.Id, LineOfBusiness__c = 'Central Title Division' );
            bu.Sales_Rep__r.UserRole.DeveloperName = 'Central_Title_Agency1';
            insert bu ; 

            try
            {
                BusinessUnits__c bu1 = new BusinessUnits__c( Contact__c = cont.Id, LineOfBusiness__c = 'Central Title Division' );
                bu1.Sales_Rep__r.UserRole.DeveloperName= 'Central_Title_Agency1';
                insert bu1 ;  
            }
            catch(DmlException de )
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

The error message I am receiving is:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Class.BusinessUnitTriggerHandlerTest.testCheckDuplicate: line 41,
>   column 1 Line 41 in my test class is:
>   bu.Sales_Rep__r.UserRole.DeveloperName = 'Central_Title_Agency1'

Answer (score 1):

This relationship field `bu.Sales_Rep__r` will only be populated in your test if:

- A relationship has been established by some logic that sets the `Sales_Rep__c` field first
- The test code then does a query that includes the related object

Otherwise `bu.Sales_Rep__r` will be null resulting in the error you see.

Comment: I tried that but I was not able to save successfully, it's throwing me "Variable doesn't exists error". can you expand your answer with any example,?

Answer (score 0):

You need to query for the User Role the same way you queried for the Profile in line 7 of your test method and assign that variable to bu.Sales_Rep__r.UserRole.